# Narrowing conversion from 'long' to signed type 'char' is implementation-defined (strtol function in C)

Tags: c, char, fgets, strtol

I'm trying to convert an inputted character to an integer by using strtol. Here's part of the source code:

```
char option;
char *endptr;

printf("=========================================Login or Create Account=========================================\n\n");
while(1) {
    printf("Welcome to the Bank management program! Would you like to 1. Create Account or 2. Login?\n>>> ");
    fgets(&option, 1, stdin);
    cleanStdinBuffer();
    option = strtol(&option, &endptr, 10);
```

In the strtol function, I'm getting a warning saying:

```
Clang-Tidy: Narrowing conversion from 'long' to signed type 'char' is implementation-defined
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This call fgets(&option, 1, stdin); does not make a sense. the object option always will be equal to 0.

Comment: You are trying to assign the `long` return value of `strtol` to a `char`. If you are sure the value will be in the [-128,127] range that isn't necessarily an issue if this is intentional, but I would advice not to reuse option and to cast the return-type of `strtol` and use `int8_t` instead(so: `int8_t value = (int8_t)strtol(...);`). If it wasn't intentional I'd recommend using `long` as type for the variable you assign the return value of `strtol`. (Furthermore the call to `fgets` is wrong.)

Comment: And you ***didn't*** get a warning for `fgets(&option, 1, stdin);`?!?!  What does `fgets()` read?

Comment: And the reason Vlad is right is because `fgets` always zero-terminates the string. If it is length 1, then the zero terminator is the only part that will fit.

Comment: Oh right I forgot about the null terminator, I meant to do `fgets(&option, 2, stdin)`

Comment: @Elijan9 can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it as an answer please? Your suggestion helped and I want to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @MatthewSchell I just did, glad to have helped.

Comment: `fgets(&option, 2, stdin) ` would be as wrong. `option` is only a single `char` that cannot hold 2 `char`s

Comment: So what should I do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang-Tidy is warning you about the implicit conversion you are doing here where you are assign the `long` return value of `strtol` to a `char`:

```
option = strtol(&option, &endptr, 10);
```

If this is intentional and you are sure the value will be in the [-128,127] range that isn't necessarily an issue (it's just a warning), but even then I would advice to explicitly cast the return-type of `strtol`, use `int8_t` instead of `char` and not reuse the `option` variable for the return value. In other words:

```
int8_t value = (int8_t)strtol(&option, &endptr, 10);
```

If it wasn't intentional I would recommend you to simply use `long` as type for the variable you assign the return value of strtol, so:

```
long value = strtol(&option, &endptr, 10);
```

What Clang-tidy doesn't warn you about is that the first argument to `strtol` should be a pointer to a char buffer containing a 0-terminated string, not a pointer to a single char. This is also an issue for [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). There are two ways to solve this, either:

1. Make option a `char` array of at least two chars,
2. Use [fgetc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) instead and modify your code into something like this:

   ```
   int option = fgetc(stdin);
   if (option == '1') {
       /*Create Account */
   } else if (option == '2') {
       /* Login */
   }
   else {
       /* Error */
   }
   ```

I think the latter looks much cleaner.

Comment: And instead of `fgetc(stdin)` it's also possible to use `getchar()`.

Answer (score 0):

`char` can only hold a very little subset of the `long` values.  strtol returns `long` and you assign it to `char`.

Answer (score 0):

This call of fgets

```
fgets(&option, 1, stdin);
```

always sets the character `option` to the terminating zero character `'\0'` provided that the user did not interrupt the input.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char c = 'A';
    
    printf( "Before calling fgets c = %d\n", c );
    
    fgets( &c, 1, stdin );
    
    printf( "After  calling fgets c = %d\n", c );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Before calling fgets c = 65
After  calling fgets c = 0
```

independent on what the user will enter. Here is the value `65` is the ASCII code of the character `'A'` that was stored in the variable c before calling `fgets`.

If you want to enter a character then you should use

```
scanf( " %c", &input );
```

Pay attention to the blank before the conversion specifier.

After this call you can check whether the user typed a digit like

```
#include <ctypes.h>

//...

if ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )input ) ) input = input - '0';
```

and set the variable input to the corresponding integer value in the range `[0, 9]`.